# Using an __init__ argument in other functions of the same class

Tags: python

So I'm trying to design a class for a weapon system in a text based game. Basically, I want all swords to deal 1-6 damage and then add damage based on the weapons modifier. I got the class to work if I call the function in the class with the modifier, but I want to set the class once and not have to type it multiple times

This is the code I have.

```
import dice #uses random generation to simulate dice rolls

class sword():

    def __init__(self, name, modifier):
        self.name = name
        self.mod = modifier

    def dmg(self, modifier):
        base = dice.d6

        self.dmg = base + modifier
        return self.dmg

x = sword("Sword of coolness", 1)
print x.name
print x.dmg(1)
```

Comment: And note that in ``sword.dmg()`` the function itself is replaced with something else, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why you did `self.mod = modifier`.  Now the value is available to methods as `self.mod`.  So you can make your method:

```
def dmg(self):
    base = dice.d6

    self.dmg = base + self.mod
    return self.dmg
```

As YS-L notes, in a comment, though, you probably don't want to do that, since you're overwriting the `dmg` method with a value.  Maybe a better idea to give the method a different name:

```
def modify_dmg(self):
    base = dice.d6

    self.dmg = base + self.mod
    return self.dmg
```

Comment: Now my question is do I even need the 'modifier' argument in the dmg method? With the 'modify_dmg' method, do I even need 'self' in front of dmg?

Comment: @CoopTang: No, you don't need it (I copied hte code from your question and forgot to remove it, but now I edited it out of my answer).  The whole point of doing this is to not have to pass it.  As for whether you need `self.dmg`, it depends what you intend this method to do.  If you don't want to "save" the `dmg` value on the object, and just want to return it, you don't need to use `self`.